# Which app generates stronger mnemonic seed?

Tags: security, mnemonic-seed, wallet-security, passphrase

Mnemonic phrase, mnemonic seed, or seed phrase are defined as a secret group of words that represent a wallet. When used in sequence they allow access to the cryptocurrencies stored within.
“Mnemonic” just means a memory aid such as rhymes, abbreviations and songs that help you remember something else. A mnemonic phrase is a group words, often 12 or more, created when a new wallet is made to store your cryptocurrency. If the computer running your crypto wallet died, was lost or even stolen, you could use your mnemonic phrase to recover your wallet and crypto. The words must be typed in exactly in the same sequence they were created. Most people store their phrases on a piece of paper and then keep that in a safe place. Your phrase must be kept secret, anyone who discovers it can steal your crypto. Mnemonic is pronounced: nuh-mon-ic.

Among the available applications (In Google Play Store and App Store) Which app generates stronger mnemonic phrases?

In general, what is the strongest way to generate mnemonic phrases?

What is the mathematical probability that someone will guess your mnemonic words randomly?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What prevents hackers from guessing seed phrases?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/106157/what-prevents-hackers-from-guessing-seed-phrases) Also we don't do app recommendations on this site, it attracts spam.

Comment: @m1xolyd1an They do not include quantum computers in their calculations.

Comment: Nor can they. If quantum computers of suffiicent complexity exist, Bitcoin private keys can be computed from public keys anyway, regardless of how random the seed phrases are.